# Reading multiple qr codes from jpeg

Tags: image-processing, qr-code

There is any software, sdk or lib that can detect multiple qr codes in one jpeg image
(its  actually screenshot from website), and decode all detected qr codes?!

Comment: You forgot to use a good search engine before asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I would give ZXing a try.
If it isn't able do fullfill your task, I would try to segment the image into subimages containing a qr-code each and the process them with ZXing.